# Is covariance stationarity a sample property?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, unit-root

I apologize in advance if this proves to be a nonsensical question but it is something I have been struggling with.

Is there a way to prove/discern that covariance stationarity is not an attribute of the sample at hand and is an attribute of the underlying process?

***edit***:

The motivation of the question comes from unit root testing; when we perform unit root testing on a series, we may accept the null ie that the series in question, has a unit root on one sample, but reject the null on a different (sub-)sample.

Answer (score 1):

Covariance stationarity is described as constancy over time of the first two moments of $X_t$. This is clearly a property of the underlying process: the moments are a process property, not a sample property.

Comment: Since samples have moments too, this reasoning would seem not to answer the question.

Comment: Let me add, then: "Clearly, the constancy implied by stationarity rules out that the moments are sample moments, for randomness would prevent these from being constant."

Comment: That helps.  I'm not sure it addresses the spirit of the question, though.  The question seems to concern making inferences about a process from a sample.  It appears to ask, "how confidently may we conclude that the process is stationary based on properties of a sample?"  To me, that looks like a version of the basic question, "how can we test any statistical hypothesis based on a sample?"  From this point of view, observing that the sample can vary because it's random is correct but not terribly useful.

Comment: May be you are right. I thought I understood the question on my first reading. I am no longer sure, so I will refrain from making additional comments that rather than being of help may obfuscate the matter.